# connections string EF Asp.Net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

How would I change the following connection string to a EF connection.?

Have been sitting quite a while now and getting a variety errors such as `Keyword not supported: 'data source'.`.

This is my current connection string

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Portal;User ID=sa;Password=xxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The IdentityModel

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an incorrect provider specified in the connection string. Change it to `System.Data.SqlClient` instead:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(local); ....."
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Wow, that did the trick, thanks, if I want to use a non entity framework orm such as Dapper as well, can I also use System.Data.SqlClient, if I may ask?

Comment: The connection string format and provider likely depend on the ORM being used. I've never used Dapper but wouldn't be surprised if it's also in this format.